# Why doesn't "dnorm" sum up to one as a probability?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, probability-density, probability-distribution

This may be some basic/fundamental question on 'dnorm' function in R. Let's say I create some z scores through z transformation and try to get the sum out of 'dnorm'.

```
 data=c(232323,4444,22,2220929,22323,13)
 z=(data-mean(data))/sd(data)
 result=dnorm(z,0,1)
 sum(result)
 [1] 1.879131
```

As above, the sum of 'dnorm' is not 1 nor 0.

Then let's say I use zero mean and one standard deviation even in my z transformation.

```
 data=c(232323,4444,22,2220929,22323,13)
 z=(data-0)/1
 result=dnorm(z,0,1)
 sum(result)
 [1] 7.998828e-38
```

I still do not get either 0 or 1 in sum.

If my purpose is to get sum of the probability equal to one as I will need for my further usage, what method do you recommend using 'dnorm' or even using other PDF functions?

Comment: The area below the density is 1 - that is the integral from -Inf to +Inf for the density function. You are doing some other thing by calculating the sum.

Comment: If I am trying to get the density 1 from dnorm to prove for my sake, what will be needed?

Comment: Read the answer of @AndersEllernBilgrau

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dnorm` returns the values evaluated in the normal probability *density* function. It does *not* return probabilities. What is your reasoning that the sum of your transformed data evaluated in the density function should equate to one or zero? You're creating a random variable, there is no reason it should ever equate exactly zero or one.

Integrating `dnorm` yields a probability. Integrating `dnorm` over the entire support of the random variable yields a probability of one:

```
integrate(dnorm, -Inf, Inf)
#1 with absolute error < 9.4e-05
```

In fact, `integrate(dnorm, -Inf, x)` conceptually equals `pnorm(x)` for all `x`.

**Edit:** In light of your comment.

The same applies to other *continuous* probability distributions (PDFs):

```
integrate(dexp, 0, Inf, rate = 57)
1 with absolute error < 1.3e-05
```

Note that the `...` argument(s) from `?integrate` is passed to the integrand.

Recall also that the Poisson distribution, say, is a *discrete* probability distribution and hence integrating it (in the conventional sense) makes no sense. A discrete probability distribution have a probability mass function (PMF) and not a PDF which actually return probabilities. In that case, it should *sum* to one.

Consider:

```
dpois(0.5, lambda = 2)
#[1] 0
#Warning message:
#In dpois(0.5, lambda = 2) : non-integer x = 0.500000
```

Summing from 0 to a 'very' large number (i.e. over the support of the Poisson distribution):

```
sum(dpois(0:1000000, lambda = 2)) 
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you. If I am trying to do the same thing with other distributions such as poisson, exponential, binomial, etc. they seemed to require some additional variables such as lamda, size, and so on. If so, may I know how I can use integrate in this general situation?

Comment: @Eric I have edited the answer. You can simply add that as an argument.